# Build assimp for windows with /MD

Tags: c++, windows, assimp

Is it possible to build assimp for windows with /MD? I've tried the following:

```
mkdir build && cd build

cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="/MD" ..
```

CMake run completes. But. During compilation, almost every component fails miserably. The client library I'm trying to link assimp to uses /MD so I'd like to use /MD for assimp as well to keep out of trouble.

EDIT

Here's some logs from compilation:

```
5>C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\include\assimp\Exceptional.h(123,1): error C2220: the following warning is treated as an error (compiling source file C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\code\Common\ImporterRegistry.cpp)
5>C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\include\assimp\Exceptional.h(123,1): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc (compiling source file C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\code\Common\ImporterRegistry.cpp)
5>C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\include\assimp\Exceptional.h(123,1): error C2220: the following warning is treated as an error (compiling source file C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\code\Common\Assimp.cpp)
5>C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\include\assimp\Exceptional.h(123,1): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc (compiling source file C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\code\Common\Assimp.cpp)
5>C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\include\assimp\Exceptional.h(123,1): error C2220: the following warning is treated as an error (compiling source file C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\code\Common\ZipArchiveIOSystem.cpp)
5>C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\include\assimp\Exceptional.h(123,1): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc (compiling source file C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\code\Common\ZipArchiveIOSystem.cpp)
5>ScenePreprocessor.cpp
5>C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\include\assimp/Exceptional.h(123,1): error C2220: the following warning is treated as an error (compiling source file C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\code\Common\BaseImporter.cpp)
5>C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\include\assimp/Exceptional.h(123,1): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc (compiling source file C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\code\Common\BaseImporter.cpp)
5>C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\include\assimp\Exceptional.h(123,1): error C2220: the following warning is treated as an error (compiling source file C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\code\Common\BaseProcess.cpp)
5>C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\include\assimp\Exceptional.h(123,1): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc (compiling source file C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\code\Common\BaseProcess.cpp)
5>SkeletonMeshBuilder.cpp
5>C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\include\assimp\Exceptional.h(123,1): error C2220: the following warning is treated as an error (compiling source file C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\code\Common\PostStepRegistry.cpp)
5>C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\include\assimp\Exceptional.h(123,1): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc (compiling source file C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\code\Common\PostStepRegistry.cpp)
5>C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\include\assimp\Exceptional.h(123,1): error C2220: the following warning is treated as an error (compiling source file C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\code\Common\Importer.cpp)
5>C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\include\assimp\Exceptional.h(123,1): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc (compiling source file C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\code\Common\Importer.cpp)
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\vector(1309,1): error C2220: the following warning is treated as an error (compiling source file 

C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\code\Common\SpatialSort.cpp)
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\vector(1299): message : while compiling class template member function 'void std::vector<Assimp::SpatialSort::Entry,std::allocator<Assimp::SpatialSort::Entry>>::_Reallocate_exactly(const unsigned __int64)' (compiling source file 
C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\code\Common\SpatialSort.cpp)
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\vector(1376): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::vector<Assimp::SpatialSort::Entry,std::allocator<Assimp::SpatialSort::Entry>>::_Reallocate_exactly(const unsigned __int64)' being compiled (compiling source file C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\code\Common\SpatialSort.cpp)
5>C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\include\assimp/SpatialSort.h(170): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<Assimp::SpatialSort::Entry,std::allocator<Assimp::SpatialSort::Entry>>' being compiled (compiling source file C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\code\Common\SpatialSort.cpp)
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\vector(1309,1): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc (compiling source file C:\path\to\Workspace\assimp\code\Common\SpatialSort.cpp)
```

The first batch of 309 total errors.

Comment: _"... almost every component fails miserably..."_ how are we supposed to help ?  Please include a sample of the errors in the question.

Comment: Nothing to do with `/MD` you need to enable C++ exception handling `/EHsc` it's on by default so check for why it's been turned off first. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/eh-exception-handling-model?view=msvc-160

Comment: So adding /EHsc did the trick. Don't know why it's turned off. Without the /MD flag all works as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable the WX option in the CMakeLists.txt got your compiler. The default for this is to have this option enabled. Maybe we should consider offering an option to disable this.